# Como adicionar campos adicionais no formulário de cadastro WordPress (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tenho um site em Wordpress, e uso um plugin de loja virtual (woocommerce) gostaria de adicionar um campo CPF/CNPJ no cadastro de cliente da loja, como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você vai usar o plugin WooCommerce Extra Checkout Fields for Brazil que foi desenvolvido por um brasileiro porque nossas lojas aqui sempre precisam ter o CPF no checkout, segue o link: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-extra-checkout-fields-for-brazil/

Comment: Muito obrigado <3